# Reference to initializer_list in noexcept specifier of std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type, initializer-list, libstdc++, noexcept

I have a question about this [code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L823):

```
    explicit constexpr
    optional(in_place_t, initializer_list<_Up> __il, _Args&&... __args)
    noexcept(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Tp, initializer_list<_Up>&,
                        _Args...>)
    : _Base(std::in_place, __il, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) { }
```

Why is the reference used here? Initializer list is passed to `std::optional` as value. I guess it might be related with the fact that it is a named argument in this context, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `is_nothrow_constructible` and various other type traits, there is a convention that an lvalue reference type `T&` means "lvalue of type `T`" whereas a non-reference type `T` means "rvalue of type `T`". In this case, a test is being done to see whether `_Tp` is nothrow constructible given that the first argument will be an *lvalue* of type `initializer_list<_Up>`.

Comment: Where is such behaviour documented? And moreover, should'nt `T&&` be used for rvalues?

Comment: @wehin19066 See https://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but I can't find anything about it on the page you mentioned. Can you elaborate on this topic? I thought that these traits should work in a simple manner like: `is_nothrow_constructible<Foo, int>`, `is_nothrow_constructible<Foo, int&>` or `is_nothrow_constructible<Foo, int&&>`.

Comment: @wehin19066 The definition of `is_nothrow_constructible` references `is_constructible`. Paragraph 8 mentions how `is_constructible` uses `declval`. `declval<T>()` returns `T&&`. According to reference collapsing rules, if `T` is `U&`, then `T&&` is `U&`. In other words an lvalue reference type supplied to `declval` will yield an lvalue argument.

Comment: One more question. How should one act while using traits like is_nothrow_constructible with forwarding references? Is it necessary to specify `&` in such case?

Comment: @wehin19066 That question deserves a separate post, because it's a different question.

Comment: Answer for future readers: In case of forwarding references you can simply use `T` in traits, collapsing will figure everything out.